# API Яндекс.Карт. Подготовка слоя тайлов

Tags: yandex-maps-api, яндекс-карты

Имеется необходимость задать маску имен файлов тайлов по типу "%z\%x\%x-%y.png" т.к. количество файлов в папке ограничено сервером. Но почему-то этот тип "%z\%x\%x-%y.png" не отображает тайлы. Как реализовать?

Comment: А где у вас возникли трудности?

Comment: "%z\%x\%x-%y.png" так тайлы не отображаются

Comment: Строковый шаблон url тайла должен формироваться согласно [документации](https://tech.yandex.ru/maps/doc/jsapi/2.1/ref/reference/Layer-docpage/?from=SO#constructor-summary), далее проверьте, что тайлы по этим url действительно доступны и API может их загрузить.

Если прооблема не решится - приведите более полный пример кода.

Answer (score 1):

Проблема решена благодаря Техподдержке. По умолчанию в программе задан шаблон с использованием устаревшей версией API 1.1. Замена на версию 2.1 решила проблему.

Comment: как заменили версию? документация не понятная